os-prober can't detect encrypted Kubuntu Installation in Triple-Boot Setup
I have a PC with three hard drives. Windows is installed on one hard drive while Ubuntu 24.04 is installed in the second hard drive. For work purposes, I bought a new hard drive where I wanted to install Kubuntu 24.04. After installation however, the Grub boot entries only show Kubuntu and Windows. If I manually switch to my old Ubuntu installation and try to find other boot partitions with os-prober, it can only find the Windows installation.
A quick-fix for me was to manually add the Kubuntu boot menu entry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and regenerate the grub config.
However, is there a way for os-prober to find my Kubuntu installation automatically from my first Ubuntu installation?
I need to mention that both the Ubuntu and Kubuntu systems are in UEFI and that the root partition in both operating systems is a logical volume and encrypted.
